# How fast is Haskell pattern matching?

Tags: performance, function, haskell, pattern-matching

We mostly use data to store values, like this:

```
data Sex = Male | Female
data Person = Person {name :: String, age :: Int, sex :: Sex}

charlie :: Person
charlie = Person "Charlie" 32 Male
```

And now we have nice functions `name` `age` and `sex` to get data values with.

But, with GADTs and Rank2, we can do something cooler:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

data Sex = Male | Female

data Data a where
    Name :: Data String
    Age  :: Data Int
    Sex  :: Data Sex

type Person = forall a. Data a -> a

charlie :: Person
charlie Name = "Charlie"
charlie Age  = 32
charlie Sex  = Male
```

So, this is pretty darned awesome. It provides us with a gloriously beautiful syntax for defining people, and makes slick use of GADTs.

But is this really any better? How is this represented at runtime? Is pattern-matching actually slower and/or bigger in representation than the data?

**lt;dr**: How fast is pattern matching compared to data lookup?

Comment: I guess YMMV on whether this is a useful use of GADTs. Still, pattern matching is the fastest thing there is: everything else depends on it (with the exception of things like floating point math). As far as "data lookup" (field accessors), you might look at core to see what they are actually doing.

Comment: Try it and see! But I would predict about an order of magnitude slowdown compared to using data. But that is more due to the overhead of calling an unknown function than due to pattern matching. The function version is also not quite the same because if the fields are more complicated expressions than just `32`, they will be re-evaluated each time. (Or you or the compiler floats it out of the function into a closure, and then you just reinvented storing data as data, with extra overhead to access it.)

Comment: An issue with  the `(->)` representation is that updating fields leaks space and lookup gets slower after each update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile your code with `-ddump-asm` you can see the pattern match is a series of comparisons and jumps with the data embedded in the instructions (load an address for the string, load a constant for the number 32, etc).

A container, such as a Map or HashMap, will be slower due to the indirection but hopefully it is obvious that a statically named variable is faster than traversing a (potentially dynamic) tree structure.